# setOnItemClickListener don't work on ListView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-listview

When I click the listview in tab Fragment 1 it won't work jump into next activities. I already setOnItemClickListener in the class, but still won't work. Now my problem is when I click the listview it won't work.

```
public class TabFragment1_Staff extends Fragment {
    ListView lsReport;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> reportlist;
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_fragment1__staff, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        reportlist = new ArrayList<>();
        lsReport = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listReport);
        loadReport();
        lsReport.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AddStatusDialogWindow.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Log.e("HANIS",reportlist.get(position).get("reportID"));
                bundle.putString("reportID",reportlist.get(position).get("reportID"));
                bundle.putString("fullName",reportlist.get(position).get("fullName"));
                bundle.putString("icNum",reportlist.get(position).get("icNum"));
                bundle.putString("phoneNum",reportlist.get(position).get("phoneNum"));
                bundle.putString("Rdate",reportlist.get(position).get("Rdate"));
                bundle.putString("Rtime",reportlist.get(position).get("Rtime"));
                bundle.putString("timeName",reportlist.get(position).get("timeName"));
                bundle.putString("typeVehicle",reportlist.get(position).get("typeVehicle"));
                bundle.putString("registrationnum",reportlist.get(position).get("registrationnum"));
                bundle.putString("location",reportlist.get(position).get("location"));
                bundle.putString("brief",reportlist.get(position).get("brief"));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***tabFragment1.xml***

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listReport"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**LoadReport class**

```
class LoadReport extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Perform api call
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            reportlist.clear();
                // Parse api response and fill in reportlist var

                ListAdapter adapter = new CustomList_StatusReport(
                        getActivity(), reportlist,
                        R.layout.activity_custom_list__status_report, new String[]
                        {"reportID","fullName","icNum","phoneNum"}, new int[]
                        {R.id.tvReport_ID,R.id.tvCompliantName,R.id.tvCompliantIC,R.id.tvCompliantPhone});
                lsReport.setAdapter(adapter);
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    LoadReport loadReport = new LoadReport();
    loadReport.execute();
}
```

Comment: Why is this one tagged `javascript`?

Comment: Can you share the CustomList_StatusReport code? I think the bug might be there

Answer (score 0):

public class CustomList_StatusReport extends SimpleAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
public LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public CustomList_StatusReport(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    mContext = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    try {
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_list__status_report, null);
        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);
        TextView reportID = vi.findViewById(R.id.tvReport_ID);
        TextView cName = vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCompliantName);
        TextView cIC = vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCompliantIC);
        TextView cPhone =  vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCompliantPhone);

        String id = (String) data.get("reportID");
        String name = (String)data.get("fullName");
        String ic = (String)data.get("icNum");
        String phone = (String)data.get("phoneNum");

        reportID.setText(id);
        cName.setText(name);
        cIC.setText(ic);
        cPhone.setText(phone);
    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In tabFragment1.xml, why you are using the below lines code?

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Please remove these if not needed and let us know whether this issue exists?

Comment: Did you added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" inside of your Linear layout tag?

Comment: No. Is that need to add inside my linear layout?

Comment: Instead of using getActivity()  inside the Fragments, use the requireActivity() method. And also if AddStatusDialogWindow.class is an Activity use intent for navigation or else if its Fragment please use fragment transaction for navigation. If any logcat error arrived, please post that too.